# Device.OnPlatform deprecated

Tags: c#, xamarin

Inside the constructor of my `ContentPage` I try to set a platform dependent padding value:

```
Padding = new Thickness(5, Device.OnPlatform(20, 5, 5), 5, 5);
```

Visual Studio underlines `Device.OnPlatform` and when I hover the mouse pointer over the method call I get the following warning:

> Devide.OnPlatform(T, T, T) is obsolete: 'Use
>   switch(RuntimePlatform) instead'.

The code initially used is from the [**e-book**](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/) 'Creating Mobile Apps with Xamarin.Forms Book' published in 2016. I 'm really surprised how fast this platform evolves!

Unfortunately I'm not aware of how `Device.OnPlatform` should be replaced using the way suggested by the warning.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/658

Answer (score 25, accepted):

2016 was the year this method became deprecated.

You're supposed to use a switch statement to determine the OS.

```
switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
    case Device.iOS:
      return new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0)
    default:
      return new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0)
 }
```

You can of course wrap this inside a function which will do the same job as you wished to do with Device.OnPlatform, but instead of calling Device.OnPlatform you'll call your own function.

Comment: It takes more code this way to do the same thing, but I understand that the newer method is easier to extend when a new device type has been added.

Comment: The `break` statements are not needed, since they are never executed.

Comment: @Encrypt0r That's correct, I added returns after I've written the basic switch statement. Edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: you edited this anwer just after a day i posted my answer .. stop copy pasting

Comment: @Rakesh What? You posted yours September 2017... Last edit on my answer is 6 August 2017.. don't know how September is before August as I'm not a time traveller... I'm also not sure what I could of copied from your answer..

Comment: Sorry @Adriani6,  for confusion

Answer (score 7):

```
switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                    Padding = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0);
                    break;

            default:
                    Padding = new Thickness(5, 5, 5, 0);
                    break;
         }
```

Answer (score 5):

In case someone has the same problem in a XAML file, this is way to get around the deprecated message:

```
<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness">
        <On Platform="iOS">0,20,0,0</On>
    </OnPlatform>
</ContentPage.Padding>
```

Comment: In case anyone copied & pasted this answer and found that it didn't work, it's because it should be "iOS", not "iOs"

Comment: Thanks to @AndrewAu ! If fixed the typo in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by using inline ternary conditional operator, this assumes you want something different for just iOS

```
Padding = new Thickness(5, (Device.RuntimePlatform==Device.iOS?20:5), 5, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

That was an incredible API, I don't think the reasons stated in [this forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/84632/redesign-onplatform), justify it's deprecation.

It could easily have been extended to support multiple platforms. I understand that [there have](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device#provide-platform-specific-values) and will be a lot of changes in the near future but I don't think any developer would pick writing cumbersome `switch` statements every single time they have to make a simple decision. Code like that gets bulky.

So, I attempted to recreate the `Device.OnPlatform<T>`

```cs
namespace Xamarin.Forms
{
    public static class DevicePlatform
    {
        private static T OnImpl<T>(T @default = default, T iOS = default, T Android = default, Func<T> computeCustom = null)
        {
            switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
            {
                case Device.iOS: return iOS;

                case Device.Android: return Android;

                default:
                    if (computeCustom == null) return @default;
                    return computeCustom.Invoke();
            }
        }

        public static T On<T>(T @default = default, T iOS = default, T Android = default) => OnImpl(@default, iOS, Android, null);

        public static T On<T>(T @default = default, T iOS = default, T Android = default, (string Platform, T Value) custom = default)
        {
            string runtimePlatform = Device.RuntimePlatform;

            return OnImpl(@default, iOS, Android, () =>
            {
                if (custom.Platform == runtimePlatform)
                    return custom.Value;

                return @default;
            });
        }

        public static T On<T>(T @default = default, T iOS = default, T Android = default, (string Platform, T Value) custom = default, (string Platform, T Value) custom2 = default)
        {
            string runtimePlatform = Device.RuntimePlatform;

            return OnImpl(@default, iOS, Android, () =>
            {
                if (custom.Platform == runtimePlatform)
                    return custom.Value;
                else if (custom2.Platform == runtimePlatform)
                    return custom2.Value;

                return @default;
            });
        }

        public static T On<T>(T @default = default, T iOS = default, T Android = default, (string Platform, T Value) custom = default, (string Platform, T Value) custom2 = default, (string Platform, T Value) custom3 = default)
        {
            string runtimePlatform = Device.RuntimePlatform;

            return OnImpl(@default, iOS, Android, () =>
            {
                if (custom.Platform == runtimePlatform)
                    return custom.Value;
                else if (custom2.Platform == runtimePlatform)
                    return custom2.Value;
                else if (custom3.Platform == runtimePlatform)
                    return custom3.Value;

                return @default;
            });
        }

        public static T On<T>(T @default = default, T iOS = default, T Android = default, (string Platform, T Value) custom = default, (string Platform, T Value) custom2 = default, (string Platform, T Value) custom3 = default, (string Platform, T Value) custom4 = default)
        {
            string runtimePlatform = Device.RuntimePlatform;

            return OnImpl(@default, iOS, Android, () =>
            {
                if (custom.Platform == runtimePlatform)
                    return custom.Value;
                else if (custom2.Platform == runtimePlatform)
                    return custom2.Value;
                else if (custom3.Platform == runtimePlatform)
                    return custom3.Value;
                else if (custom4.Platform == runtimePlatform)
                    return custom4.Value;

                return @default;
            });
        }

        public static T On<T>(T @default = default, T iOS = default, T Android = default, params (string Platform, T Value)[] customPlatforms)
        {
            string runtimePlatform = Device.RuntimePlatform;

            return OnImpl(@default, iOS, Android, () =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < customPlatforms.Length; i++)
                {
                    var platform = customPlatforms[i];
                    if (platform.Platform == runtimePlatform)
                        return platform.Value;
                }

                return @default;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample on how it can be used:

```
Padding = new Thickness(0, DevicePlatform.On(0, iOS: 20, Android: 0, custom: (Device.Tizen, 34)));
```

As you can see our cool API is back and [Tizen](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/658#discussion_r93835390) stays remembered forever.

I plan on making a micro nuget package out of this, so I'm open to corrections and help in any form.

Cheers