# Xamarin apps confusion between Device.OnPlatform and Switch()

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm currently working on a project on my internship that requires me to use an outdated project. 
I'm still trying to build the project, got rid of all the error but now this warnings of obsolete lines don't let me get through.

I have the following error :

> Warning   CS0618  'Device.OnPlatform(T, T, T)' is obsolete: 'OnPlatform<> (generic) is obsolete as of version 2.3.4. Please use switch(RuntimePlatform) instead.'

And the code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MobileMedico.Classes
{
    public static class BoolResources
    {
        public static readonly bool ShouldShowBoxView =  Device.OnPlatform(true, false, true);
    }
}
```

Sadly I don't know how to use the `Switch` method. Can Anyone help me?

Comment: Is this related to java? if not then remove java tag .

Comment: @ADM sure not. Tag removed.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526185/device-onplatform-deprecated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Device.OnPlatform deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45526185/device-onplatform-deprecated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that method is now obsolete. In order to target specific devices you have to indeed use a switch statement that gets the runtime platform as a parameter.This is an example.

```
  static class AppConstants
{
    public static readonly Thickness PagePadding = GetPagePadding();

    private static Thickness GetPagePadding()
    {
        double topPadding;

        switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                topPadding = 20;
                break;
            default:
                topPadding = 0;
                break;
        }

        return new Thickness(5, topPadding, 5, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) is a basic C# keyword

```
bool ShouldShowBoxView = false;

switch(Device.RuntimePlatform)
{
    case Device.iOS:
       ShouldShowBoxView = true;
       break;
   case Device.Android:
       ShouldShowBoxView = false;
       break;
}
```